# Matrices en java ()

Tags: java

En una `matriz` al momento que ingreso un número por ejemplo un (1), el resto de la fila se me rellene de cero.

```
public Bidimensional (int f, int c){
      mat= new int [f][c];
}

public int[][] matriz ( int col,int fil){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

         mat[i][j] =Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su voto para el canditado " + "A[" + i + "][" + j + "] " ));

        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Comment: estas seguro? el codigo no parece decir eso...estas pidiendo un numero por posicion...

Comment: y que quieres que haga el código? Si puedes dar más detalles al formular la pregunta!

Comment: Se te rellena de 0 no por que java te lo rellene al tu meter un numero, sino que con el simple hecho de crear una matriz java pone por defecto en todos los espacios de la matriz un 0. Si te devuelve los valores que esperabas y algunos ceros de mas es que a la hora de crear la matriz no indicaste bien las dimensiones, por lo tanto te ha creado una matriz mas grande rellenando todos los huecos con ceros por defecto.

Answer (score -2):

En el primer `for` tienes `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++);`
Cuando debería ser `for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++);`